# Python plot legend updating from a data file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have several data files each with three columns:

```
    k t x
    1 0 0
    1 1 10
    1 2 20
```

etc, for different values of k.

I want to make a plot of x vs t in **Python**, which is quite easy. Now, I want to make a legend showing "k=1". Now, the simplest way I can think of is to write each legend by hand (quite boring!).

Is there any efficient way to update the legends automatically, i.e., the legends "k=?" where the `?' will pick up the values automatically from the data file?

The example I have tried is the basic plotting so that I have not reproduced here, and for the legend part I really don't know how to proceed!

Please Help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following minimal example. Since `k` seems to be the same over the complete file, you may simply use the first entry of `k` to put it into the legend.

```
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

u = u"""k t x
        1 0 0
        1 1 10
        1 2 20"""

k, t, x = np.loadtxt(io.StringIO(u), skiprows=1, unpack=True)

plt.plot(t,x, label="k={}".format(k[0]))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```